# Combine records from two tables in one query

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have the following tables,

select * from tbl1;

```
+------+------------+---------+----------+
| id   | userId     | part_id | url      |
+------+------------+---------+----------+
|    1 | 155        |       1 | "http:/" |
+------+------------+---------+----------+
```

select * from tbl2;

```
+------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| id   | userId     | part_id | tbl2_id1    |   tbl2_id2 | notes     |
+------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|    1 | 155        |       1 |  12         |          1 | note 1    |
|    2 | 155        |       1 |  12         |          2 | note 2    |
+------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

As you can see tbl2 has two FK (userId and part_id), tbl2_id1 and tbl2_id2 are the PK of tbl2.

My question is how can I get the three records from both tables in one query?

Something like this

```
  1 | 155        |       1 |"http:/"   | from tbl1
  1 | 155        |       1 | note 1    | from tbl2
  2 | 155        |       1 | note 2    | from tbl2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `union all`:

```
select id, userId, part_id, url, 'from tbl1' as which
from tbl1
union all
select id, userId, part_id, notes, 'from tbl2'
from tbl2;
```